# django - set user permissions when user is automatically created using get_or_create

Tags: python, django, django-admin, django-authentication

Django 1.5, python 2.6

The model automatically creates a user under certain conditions:

```
User.objects.get_or_create(username=new_user_name, is_staff=True) 
u = User.objects.get(username=new_user_name)
u.set_password('temporary')
```

In addition to setting the username, password, and is_staff status, I would like to set the user's permissions - something like:

```
u.user_permissions('Can view poll')
```

or

```
u.set_permissions('Can change poll')
```

Is this possible?  Thank you!

Answer (score 78, accepted):

Use [`add` and `remove`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/default/#permissions-and-authorization) methods:

```
 from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
 permission = Permission.objects.get(name='Can view poll')
 u.user_permissions.add(permission)
```

Comment: Better to use ```codename``` than name to get the Permission

Answer (score 28):

Andrew M. Farrell's answer is correct. I only add  the use of [get_user_model()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model) and a full example.

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission
u = get_user_model().objects.get(username=new_user_name)
```

To get the permission you can use

```
permission = Permission.objects.get(name='Can view poll')
```

or

```
permission = Permission.objects.get(codename='can_view_poll')
```

then add it to the user permissions set

```
u.user_permissions.add(permission)
```

Comment: In the first snippet. it should be ```u = get_user_model().objects.get(username=new_user_name)```. Django Doc for reference  https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/customizing/#django.contrib.auth.get_user_model

Answer (score 1):

Using codename filed:-

```
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model
from django.contrib.auth.models import Permission

user = get_user_model().objects.get(name="test")
permission = Permission.objects.get(codename='view_poll')
user.user_permissions.add(permission)

# Check permission 
print(user.has_perm("<app_name).view_poll"))
```