# How to deny permission to a user of one kind from accessing the view of other user through url in django?

Tags: django, django-permissions

In my project, I've got different types of Users like this:

`User
 |-Client
 |-Employee
   |-Technical Manager
   |-Service Manager 
   |-Production Manager`

No user can access the view of other user by `url`. A client cannot access profile of a Technical Manager through the url `/officer/profile` which is assigned for Technical Manager's profile.

In order to do so, In my `Client class` in the `models.py`, I used this code snippet:

`class Client(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        permissions = (
            ('view_client', 'view_Client'),
        )`

Then for each view I used a decorator like this:
`@permission_required(lambda u: u.has_perm('authentication.view_client'))`

Then I'm logging in as a technical manager and trying to access with this url:
`/client/profile`

Then I got the error `function object is not iterable`.

I was creating my user in an app called `authentication`. The `models,py` looks like this: 
'

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    user_sex = (('MALE', 'Male'), ('FEMALE', 'Female'))
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=6, default='Male', choices=user_sex)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    city = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    state = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    country = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    phone = PhoneNumberField(blank=True)
    zip = models.IntegerField(null=True, blank=True)
    about = models.CharField(max_length=250, null=True, blank=True)
    email_confirmed = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    account_type = models.IntegerField(default=-1)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_profile'


class Employee(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    manager = models.ForeignKey('self', null=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    designation = models.CharField(max_length=6)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_employee'


class Client(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'auth_client'


@receiver(post_save, sender=User)
def update_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        Profile.objects.create(user=instance)
    instance.profile.save()
    if instance.profile.account_type == 0:
        if not Client.objects.filter(user=instance).exists():
            Client.objects.create(user=instance)
            instance.client.save()
        else:
            instance.client.save()
    if instance.profile.account_type == 1 or instance.profile.account_type == 2 or instance.profile.account_type == 3:
        if not Employee.objects.filter(user=instance).exists():
            Employee.objects.create(user=instance)
            instance.employee.save()
        else:
            instance.employee.save()
```

'

Profile class is kinda big. Please ignore it. Now what I wanted is that I would assign the permission each time a different user has been created of any types.

How to resolve the error and how can I accomplish this, so that one type of user cannot access the view of others' by typing the url?

**Edited after the comment from `souldeux`**

Here is one of my views where a client can update his contact info:

```
@login_required(login_url='/login/')
@permission_required(lambda u: u.has_perm('authentication.view_client'))
def contact(request):
    user = request.user
    if request.method == 'POST':
        # form = ContactForm()
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user.profile.address = form.cleaned_data.get('address')
            user.profile.city = form.cleaned_data.get('city')
            user.profile.state = form.cleaned_data.get('state')
            user.profile.country = form.cleaned_data.get('country')
            user.profile.phone = form.cleaned_data.get('phone')
            user.profile.zip = form.cleaned_data.get('zip')


            user.save()
            messages.add_message(request,
                                 messages.SUCCESS,
                                 'Your contact was successfully edited.')

    else:

        form = ContactForm(instance=user, initial={
            'address': user.profile.address,
            'city': user.profile.city,
            'state': user.profile.state,
            'country': user.profile.country,
            'phone': user.profile.phone,
            'zip': user.profile.zip,
        })
    return render(request, 'client/client_contact.html', {'form': form})
```

And the error I got:

```
TypeError at /client/picture

'function' object is not iterable

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/client/picture
Django Version:     1.11.6
Exception Type:     TypeError
Exception Value:    

'function' object is not iterable

Exception Location:     /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/contrib/auth/models.py in has_perms, line 285
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python2.7
Python Version:     2.7.12
Python Path:    

['/home/shamsad/PycharmProjects/OpenGMS',
 '/home/shamsad/PycharmProjects/OpenGMS',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/home/shamsad/.local/lib/python2.7/site-packages',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0']

Server time:    Sun, 29 Oct 2017 16:21:25 +0000
```

Comment: Could you post the full traceback for your error, and your view? The view is where we would be checking whether or not a given request can access the content it's asking for

Comment: I've edited the my question.

Comment: I've also posted the traceback

Answer (score 0):

Rather than passing a lambda function in a `permission_required` decorator, re-write the permission test as a standalone function and apply it via a `method_decorator` that works on the `dispatch` method:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class

[How to use permission_required decorators on django class-based views](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6069070/how-to-use-permission-required-decorators-on-django-class-based-views)

You can also use `@user_passes_test` to decorate your function-based views. For instance, perhaps there is a view you want to be visible only to those users associated with a `Client` object:

```
def user_has_client(user)
    return hasattr(user, 'Client')

@user_passes_test(user_has_client, login_url='/')
def my_protected_view(request):
    ...
```

You could check for user permissions in your test as well: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/contrib/auth/#django.contrib.auth.models.User.has_perm

Comment: Do I have to assign permission in the `post signal` each time an user has been created?

Comment: If you want consistent behavior across all users, then yes. Here is how you would do that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20361235/django-set-user-permissions-when-user-is-automatically-created

Comment: `decorator, re-write the permission test as a standalone function` I didn't quite understand this part, sorry my bad. So far I know that in the model, I have to use the permission in the `meta` class.

Comment: The `permissions` definition in your model defines the permissions users can have in relation to that model. You have defined a `view_client` permission, and now you need to add that permission to the relevant users. Use the `add` and `remove` methods detailed in the last link to set permissions in your signal; then when your view is processing any given request, it can look at request.user and see if that user has the appropriate permissions. Take some time to read over the three links I've provided and the documentation they link; they will fully explain how to solve your problem

Comment: I was thingking something like this. So, with the help of this, if another user kind types in the url `/client/contact` he won't be able to view it, right?

Comment: If you implement it properly, yes; you need to read the docs I have linked for you to understand how it works and exactly what you need to do. Again: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-the-class The examples here use `login_required` as the method decorator but you could easily pass in your own test.

Comment: Thanks for your help

Comment: I have edited in a code example and a bit of extra info; I hope this helps.